# On topic or not? Heartbleed - List of vulnerable websites

Tags: discussion

I am seeing reports on Twitter and elsewhere that folks have confirmed they can see random usernames and passwords as they "attack" various high-profile websites including Yahoo and LastPass.

This is a forum for information security professionals, and as such, I think it would be helpful to have a list of known (popular) websites and cloud service providers that are currently vulnerable.

That said, I can see that this would be somewhat of an open-ended question, and possibly something that will change rapidly as various service providers patch their systems.

Would a question like this be constructive, or would it be frowned upon (if constructive, I think it would probably be good to make it canonical)?

Comment: It would need to practically be a live feed as systems are patched. I would think infosec professionals would assume the worst and consider all services compromised.

Comment: I think it would not be helpful at the moment; since it was only recently made public, a great many sites will be vulnerable and impossible to avoid. After a few days/weeks have passed, a list of "still vulnerable" sites would be useful to indicate websites that should improve their procedures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A rapidly changing list would not be very helpful here. There are likely to be sites that will host lists and that have a better infrastructure and policy to do so, so I'd say that no, it wouldn't be on-topic or constructive here.

Additionally, as Raystafarian commented - it is not going to be useful to professionals to have such a list. Each organisation that has SSL servers should be checking for themselves, and until they have, preparing for the worst.

Comment: I agree with this.

Comment: Agreed. List questions aren't a good fit for StackExchange in general - highly volatile lists even more so.

Comment: Additionally, assuming the list would be accurate, it could become a 'hit-list' for attackers.